# Reiterate through classes inside a class inside a div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">  
     <div class="cell">a</div>
     <div class="cell">b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="cell">d</div>
     <div class="cell">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I reiterate through them in a way that I create the same structure but with `<table>` instead of `<div id="table">`, `<tr>` instead of `<div class="row">` and `<td>` with the content of the div instead of `<div class="cell">`;

I tried doing something like

```
 let topics_table = '<table>'
                $('#table > .row').each(function(){
                    topics_table += '<tr>'
                        $(this + ' .cell').each(function(that){
                            topics_table += '<td>' + that.text() + '</td>'    
                        })
                    topics_table += '</tr>';
                })
 topics_table += '</table>`
```

But I get an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this + ' .cell')
```

Should be

```
$(this).find('.cell')
// or
$('.cell', this)
```

You're trying to concatenate a string to a DOM Element.

```
.each(function(that){
   topics_table += '<td>' + that.text() + '</td>'    
})
```

^^ that is also an issue, because jQuery passes the index in as the first argument, not the element.

```
.each(function(index, that){
   topics_table += '<td>' + that.innerText + '</td>'    
})
```